# How to Authenticate each REST request with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, authentication, header

I am Building Spring Rest Application and need to Authenticate each request with header. please provide help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a interceptor to do this.

1. Add a interceptor class by implement class `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`
2. Add your interceptor class to config class or config xml.
3. Auth you request in selfImplInterceptor like:

`public boolean preHandler(HttpServletRequest request, ...){
    if (request.getHeader("auth-key").length()==12){
        return true; // pass this request
    }
}`